# 2D engine with OpenGL: Use Z buffer or own implementation for sprite sorting?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, layer

If I was making a 3D engine, the answer to this question would be clear: I'd go for using the depth buffer instead of thinking of sorting all my polygons on my own.

However, this is a different situation with 2D, because here layers can be implemented easily without the help of OpenGL - and you then could even sort and move sprites within layers. (Which isn't possible in OpenGL afaik)

- (Why) should I use the OpenGL depth buffer instead of a C++ layer system running on the CPU?
- How much slower would the depth buffer version be?

It is clear to me that making a layer system in C++ would impose as good as no performance impact at all, as I have to iterate over the sprites for rendering in any case.

Comment: Entirely up to you I think ... I chose rendering my own layers in plain C++ when making a 2D tile scrolling engine in DirectX. However my sprites consisted of a single texture as well (in other words shadows were built in to the frame I only had 2 layers tiles and sprites)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to do it in software since you probably want to use transparency on your sprites and that implies you render them from back to front. Also sorting a couple of sprites shouldn't be that CPU demanding.

Answer (score 5):

Direct answers:

- allowing the GPU to use the depth buffer would allow you to dynamically adjust the draw order of things without any on-CPU shuffling and would free you from having to assign things to different layers in situations where doing so is a bit of a fiction — for example, you could have effects like projectiles that come from the background towards and then in front of the player, without having to figure out which layer to assign them to all the time
- on the GPU, the use of a depth would have no measurable effect, even if you're on an embedded chip, a plug-in card from more than a decade ago or an integrated part; they're so fundamental to modern GPUs that they've been optimised down to costing nothing in practical terms

However, I'd imagine you actually want to do it on the CPU for the simple reason of treating transparency correctly. A depth buffer stores one depth per pixel, so if you draw a near transparent object then attempt to draw something behind it, the thing behind won't be drawn even though it should be visible. In a 2d game it's likely that anti-aliasing will give your sprites partially transparent edges; if you submit drawing to the GPU in draw order then your partial transparencies will always be composited correctly. If you leave the z-buffer to do it then you risk weird looking fringing.

Answer (score 5):

Use both, if you can.

Depth information is nice for post-processing and stuff like 3D-glasses, so you shouldn't throw it away. These kinds of effects can be very nice for 2D games.
Also, if you draw your (opaque) layers front to back, you can save fill-rate because the Z-Buffer can do the clipping for you (Depth tests are faster than actual drawing).
Depth testing is usually almost free, especially when you got hierarchical Z info. Because of this and the fill-rate savings, using depth testing will probably be even faster.

On the other hand, the software sorting is nice so you can actually do front to back rendering for opaque sprites and it's mandatory to do alpha-blending right (of course, you draw these sprites back to front).